# Error using subscript of optional array

Tags: swift, ios8

When using this code:

```
let result: AnyObject! = hitResults[0]
```

I am getting the following error:

> `[AnyObject]?` does not have a member named `subscript`

Containing function for context:

```
   func handleTap(gestureRecognize: UIGestureRecognizer) {
        // retrieve the SCNView
        let scnView = self.view as SCNView

        // check what nodes are tapped
        let p = gestureRecognize.locationInView(scnView)
        let hitResults = scnView.hitTest(p, options: nil)

        // check that we clicked on at least one object
        if hitResults?.count > 0 {
            // retrieved the first clicked object
            let result: AnyObject! = hitResults[0]

            // get its material
            let material = result.node!.geometry?.firstMaterial

            // highlight it
            SCNTransaction.begin()
            SCNTransaction.setAnimationDuration(0.5)

            // on completion - unhighlight
            SCNTransaction.setCompletionBlock {
                SCNTransaction.begin()
                SCNTransaction.setAnimationDuration(0.5)

                material?.emission.contents = UIColor.blackColor()

                SCNTransaction.commit()
            }

            material?.emission.contents = UIColor.redColor()

            SCNTransaction.commit()
        }
    }
```

Does anyone know what the issue here is?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

This happens because `hitTest` returns an optional array, so you need to unwrap before using it.

Instead of checking that the hitResults has a count > 0, you could check that there the first object exists, and then proceed to using that object

```
if let firstHit = scnView.hitTest(p, options: nil)?.first {
    // safely use firstHit here...
}
```

Answer (score 0):

You can't use a subscript on an optional array. `[AnyObject]?` Is an optional array of type AnyObject. If you are sure that hitResults is non-nil, you can unwrap it with ! then use a subscript.

```
let result: AnyObject! = hitResults![0]
```

Answer (score 0):

Since `hitResults` is an `[AnyObject]?`, you can't call subscript on it without unwrapping it first. The safest way to do this is using optional binding, like so:

```
// check that we clicked on at least one object
if hitResults?.count > 0 {
    // retrieved the first clicked object
    if let result: AnyObject = hitResults?[0] {
        /* safely use result here */
    }
}
```

Or, even better, you can use optional binding with the `first` property of `Array` which returns the first element in the array if the `Array` is not empty, or `nil`:

```
// check that we clicked on at least one object and retrieve it
if let result = hitResults?.first {
    /* safely use result here */
}
```